# Pyramid (Pylons/repoze.bfg) LDAP authentication

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, openldap, pyramid

Have anybody ever tried to use authentication mechanisms through LDAP / AD (OpenLDAP / ActiveDirectory)? Any middleware to automate these things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/). It has a plugin for LDAP authentication. It's built for handling common authentication methods using WSGI middleware and is the most prevalent solution to handling SSO.